# Ctrl-Alt-Del Change password missing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, passwords, ctrl-alt-delete

I disabled the `Remove Change Password` but the change password option is still not showing with Ctrl-Alt-Del.

How do I get it back?

I need it badly because there is a domain where I connect only via VPN and have no access to any servers except the DCs.

(Why must Microsoft make things more difficult instead of easier?)

---

My policy setting for this item is:

[image]

Comment: Microsoft didn't remove it, an Administrator on your domain removed it, this option can be disabled at the group policy level.

Comment: My PC is not joined to any domain. I applied the policy using gpedit.msc (User Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Atrl+Alt+Del Options). It shows Disabled. Could there be another overriding policy somewhere else?

Comment: I just added an answer with two method from SevenForums.com but the GP settings should be set to either **Enabled** or **Not Configured**.... your problem is likely due to you having the option set to disabled as you commented above stating. If needed **Download** the registry file and apply it, reboot, and then test again. Be sure to reboot regardless after you make either change.

Comment: @OldGeezer - If you are not connected to a domain why did you mention the Domain Controller?  I am honestly confused by the question, now that I read your comment to the answer you received, you specifically Disabled this policy but then switched it to Enabled.

Comment: It is a partner network I have to connect (to read their mail. I am given connectivity to their Exchange servers only, through VPN). In the past, I just pressed Ctrl-Alt-Del on my PC to change their password.

Answer (score 6):

> ### [How to Add or Remove "Change Password" from the CTRL+ALT+DEL Screen](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/63014-ctrl-alt-del-screen-add-remove-change-password.html)
>
> ### Using a REG File Download
>
> To Add Change Password to CTRL+ALT+DEL Screen for Only Current User
>
> - A) Click on the Download button below to download the file below.
>
>   - **Add_Change_Password_CTRL+ALT+DEL.reg**
>
> ### [<kbd>**`Download`**</kbd>](https://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/53515d1277996001-ctrl-alt-del-screen-add-remove-change-password-add_change_password_ctrl-alt-del.reg)
>
> ---
>
> ### Through the Local Group Policy Editor
>
> 1. Open the **all users**, **specific users or groups**, or **all users except administrators** Local Group Policy Editor for how you
>      want this policy applied.
> 2. In the left pane, click on to expand **User Configuration**, **Administrative Templates**, **System**, and **Ctrl+Alt+Del**. (See screenshot below)
>
> [image]
>
> 3. In the right pane, right click on **Remove Change Password** and click on **Edit**. (See screenshot above)
> 4. **To Add Change Password to CTRL+ALT+DEL Screen**
>
>    - A) Select (dot) either **Not Configured** or **Disabled**. (See screenshot below step 6)
>    - B) Go to step 6.
> 5. **To Remove Change Password from CTRL+ALT+DEL Screen**
>
>    - A) Select (dot) **Enabled**. (See screenshot below step 6)
> 6. Click on **OK**. (See screenshot below)
>
> [image]
>
> 7. Close the Local Group Policy Editor window.
>
> [Source](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/63014-ctrl-alt-del-screen-add-remove-change-password.html)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did. It was at Not Configured. I set it to Disabled, which means to be explicit that the Change Password option be not removed. This is a standalone PC. I wonder why the Change Password wasn't there earlier when this was at Not Configured.

Comment: It has been set to Disabled, but the change password option is still not there. It's frustrating.

Comment: Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.1198).  Thanks for helping.

Comment: @OldGeezer Another suggestion would be to run `SFC /SCANNOW` from an elevated command prompt and just let that run, reboot and confirm afterwards if that fixes it. Not sure how you feel about upgrading Windows 10 to 1703 too but thought that'd be worth mentioning to you for your thoughts, Did you upgrade from a previous version of Windows to Windows 10 on this system? If so, what was the prior version before you upgraded if that's applicable rather than a fresh new Windows 10 install if you know what I mean?

Comment: Mine was a **clean** install from the ISO image downloaded from Microsoft. I usually let the upgrade perform according to Windows Updates. Will try SFC later.

Comment: @OldGeezer In addition to the above comment I left a minute or so ago above, you can check here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/features?OCID=win10_null_vanity_win10features and select the **Download Update Assistant** option to download the file that'll upgrade to the latest build of Windows 10. I don't recall Windows Update prompting me to upgrade to the latest version until a while ago it was a couple build behind. I checked it manually on my system from 1607 to 1703 but something to consider potentially if you want as well. Don't forget to read my above comment too just in case.

Comment: Regarding the two registry keys: the first one (HKLU) does not have a System folder under Policies. The second one has System, but there is no DisableChangePassword entry. Should I create one here? What should the type and value be?

Comment: That's the way it is supposed to be the way you see it when the Change Password should be showing just fine so I don't think that's the problem. Try the `SFC /SCANNOW` and see if that helps any or if the cbs.log file in the command window text once it completes shows any errors, etc. once it completes.

Comment: Does it affect all users?  Does it affect a new user?  Does it affect admin vs standard users?

Comment: @OldGeezer That's a good point Chris mentioned, could it be a profile setting that's locking that profile down, corruption, etc. for just that one profile. I just read the comments in the question too about connecting to a VPN. Have you asked the partner network IT support staff if they are aware of this with Windows 10 using that login for the VPN for the Exchange access? I'm surprising they are requiring VPN for email though so see if they have other secure solutions for access in case that is related too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your account is tied to a Microsoft Live Account, and you must change the password using the Settings dialog/"Sign-In Options"/Password section/"Change" button...

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 0):

"Perhaps your account is tied to a Microsoft Live Account, and you must change the password using the Settings dialog/"Sign-In Options"/Password section/"Change" button..."

--This.

The way to check this is first to go to Settings -> Accounts -> Your Info. If you see "Sign in with a local account instead" you are signed in with a Microsoft account and you won't have "Change a password" option. You'll have to sign in to microsoft.com to do that. If you prefer a simple password (MS insists on an 8-character minimum, which I refuse to live with) you could consider switching to local user.