# Missing Change password option on Windows 10 Pro Ctrl+Alt+Del screen

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-10-v1909

I have a Windows 10 Pro system (version 1909 Build 18363.535), not joined to a domain. When I press Ctrl+Alt+Del there is no Change password option.

[image]

I've tried using gpedit.msc and set:
User Configuration | Administrative Templates | System | Ctrl+Alt+Del Options |  "Remove change password" setting to Disabled, then ran GPupdate from an elevated prompt, but it's still gone.

If I try to set the password in compmgmt.msc I'm presented with a message that data could be lost and to do it using Ctrl+Alt+Del.

Why would this be missing?  What else can I do to get the Change password option to appear here as I believe it should?

Comment: See what you can do using the Local Users and Groups console. Open a Run box with Win + R and open it with `lusrmgr.msc` - under users, you should be able to check to see if "User Cannot Change Password" is checked in the user's properties.

Comment: @Lahru - While you are verifying if the user is allowed to change their password, please verify when the password was last changed for the user, by default users are not allowed to change their password if they have recently changed it.

Comment: See if this helps>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1180120/ctrl-alt-del-change-password-missing-in-windows-10

Comment: @SamForbis "User Cannot Change Password" is NOT ticked

Comment: @Ramhound  ran from elevated PS prompt Get-LocalUser  CMDlet and the PasswordLastSet is 12/24/2019 so when you say "...by default [not allowed to change password if recently changed it."], what do you mean by "Recently"?  Also default minimum password age is only 1 day, or can be 0 if the account is set to "Never Expire"  which it is.  PasswordRequired property is 'True', UserMayChangePassword property is 'True'  account is also a member of local Administrators.

Comment: @Moab  Comment at the bottom of the page you linked gives the answer [...account is tied to a Microsoft Live Account, and you must change the password using the Settings dialog/"Sign-In Options"/Password section/"Change" button...]  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

account is tied to a Microsoft Live Account, and you must change the password using the Settings dialog/"Sign-In Options"/Password section/"Change" button...